# Prevent Element from Expanding

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table which has a column for URLs and sometimes the URL can get pretty long.

I set the table to have a specific width but there are times when the URL wouldn't even break itself and expand the table which messes up with the layout.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xyhz7p0/) for you to take a look at and I'll provide the codes below:

#### HTML

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>http://www.exampledomain.org/How-We-Work/General-Information/General-Opportunities/Open-Concept-Memo-Global-Test-Cases</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Another Test</td>
      <td>http://www.exampledomain.org/search?q=flagship+collaborative+research+program&btnG=Google%2BSearch&client=csiro_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=csiro_frontend&proxyreload=0&sort=date%253AD%253AL%253Ad1&wc=200&wc_mc=1&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&exclude_apps=1&site=Main&filter=0&getfields=*&sourcepage={CB41B120-BEE8-4511-9BED-A5E43D32381D}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
table {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you use https://goo.gl/ to shorten the URLs?

Comment: @mlegg Sorry but no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/0xyhz7p0/1/

```
td {
   word-break: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table-layout: fixed` and `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px;
}
td {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>http://www.exampledomain.org/How-We-Work/General-Information/General-Opportunities/Open-Concept-Memo-Global-Test-Cases</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>URL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Another Test</td>
      <td>http://www.exampledomain.org/search?q=flagship+collaborative+research+program&btnG=Google%2BSearch&client=csiro_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=csiro_frontend&proxyreload=0&sort=date%253AD%253AL%253Ad1&wc=200&wc_mc=1&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&exclude_apps=1&site=Main&filter=0&getfields=*&sourcepage={CB41B120-BEE8-4511-9BED-A5E43D32381D}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm voting this up because it's doable but I have to do something like https://jsfiddle.net/0xyhz7p0/2/ just to keep the first column from getting a percentage based width. I would prefer Alqin's answer as it's a very simple solution. Still, thanks!